# How to enable back button wen setCancelable is set to false in Progress Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, progress-bar

I have a progress dialog, I have set `progressDialog.setCancelable(false);`,but i want to give user the option to use back button and go to previous activity.

Is it possible to enable back button when `setCancable`is set to false

Comment: are you launching a dialog from inside an activity or are you using a dialogFragment?

Comment: override `onBackPressed` in your Activity, and check if dialog is showing - then hide it

Answer (score 0):

Just finish your activity when the user presses the back button. Then they should return to the previous activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```